# Error Message in Parse.com CloudCode - parse update?

Tags: parse-platform

My Cloud Code below was working fine until recently. Now I'm getting an error message (see below) but don't know why. My guess is Parse updated some of their API, but I do not know for sure. Also, I'm not a JavaScript person and therefore are hoping for some insight. Does somebody have a hint for me?

```
Parse.Cloud.define("setUserAnswersForQuestionIds", function(request, response) {

    //the following line creates the error
    var userId = request.user.get("userId"),

    endpointURL = constants.apiURL2 + userId + "/preferences";
...
```

Here is the error message

```
{
 "code": 141,
 "error": "TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of null\n    at  vivanda_api.js:241:29"
}
```

Comment: It thinks "userId" is null (undefined)

Comment: I think you are correct. the thing is why all of the sudden?

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the request from a non-active user session: i.e. no one is logged in, thus request.user is null.

Comment: request.user is null. It's saying that "get" is not a method that is defined for type "null." Try just printing out request.user. It will show that it is null and then that means that no one is logged in client side.

Comment: I2015-08-25T16:19:59.327Z]request user ->null
I2015-08-25T16:19:59.328Z]request para ->undefined 

question still is why now and without any change?

Comment: Is it a Facebook login app?

Comment: no, it calls into a 3rd party API. no changes their either. this must be happening because parse changed something.

Comment: I was just saying, on your client side app, whatever is calling the cloud function, the user somehow got deauthed. Make sure in whatever client side code is sending that request, you can verify that the current user is not null.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87905/discussion-between-dirklx-and-alexkoren).